# Alternatives to assimp

Tags: c++, 3d

I have downloaded assimp API and tried to build it with mingw. Unfortunately that doesn't work. I asked how to fix it here and on some other forums, but got no real answer. The only answer I got is to change the compiler which I am not going to do, but I am ready to change the API instead. Does anybody know a good C++ API with the same feature which can be build as static lib with mingw and has no dependencies to external APIs? By features I mean reading and writing the 3D formats. It should at least be able to read all formats supported by assimp.